# what determines the order of questions in the stack?

Tags: support, questions

When I see a question in the "all questions" list on page one, can I assume it is a new question, or an old one with a new answer, or do the questions shuffle automatically?

Answer (score 7):

It depends on your sorting method. [El'endia Starman's answer](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5758/10486) describes when you have the sort set to "[active](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active)", but there are 5 other options that could be selected:

- [newest](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) (sorts by newest **question**)
- [featured](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured) (shows only posts that have active bounties pending)
- [frequent](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) (sort by [*recent?*] page views)
- [votes](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) (by highest votes for the question)
- [unanswered](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered) (questions with no upvoted answers yet)

Answer (score 2):

On the front page, questions are sorted by those most recently active. This includes:

- The question was posted
- An answer was posted
- The question (including tags) was edited
- An answer was edited
- A bounty was added
- The question was closed or reopened

And maybe one or two other actions. So questions are sorted by which ones had these actions done more recently.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Pam's referring to this page: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions rather than this one: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/ which you seem to be referring to.

Comment: @bruisedreed: Huh, I guess you're probably right. +1'd your answer.